# Which class is loaded in a Maven project when multiple versions of same library are declared as dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

The following is clearly bad practice but my question is out of pure curiosity: If I have a Maven project with two versions of the same library in the dependencies (e.g. jetty server in the `pom.xml` fraction below), then I import a class in my code (e.g. java code below), which version is the class picked up from?

```
  <project>
   ....

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
     <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
     <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
     <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
     <version>8.1.17.v20150415</version>
   </dependency>

   ....
   </project>
```

And the java code:

```
package test.hello;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;

public class Hello {

    Server server;

    public Hello() {
        server = new Server();
    }
}
```

Is the `server` object created from the old version class or the new version class? Maven does not complain about any ambiguity. It just loads a class; I don't know which.

Comment: If it really that in your pom you should simply remove it and decide which one you would like to have. I assume you have a warning curing the build!

Comment: This question is purely out of curiosity. I could imagine a case where project `A` depends on artifact `xyz` version `1` as well as on project `B`, which depends on artifact `xyz` version `2`. Wouldn't there be ambiguity?

Comment: Maven 3.x uses the latest version based on version comparison.

Comment: There is only ambiguity if there is no way to resolve which one to use.

Comment: @Thea The scenario in your comment is completely different than the one in your question.  The question example should not happen.  A single build element should know what library it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Maven has nothing to do with loading jars or classes. Maven only gathers all the dependancy. Its upto your classloader to decide what to load when.

If you have two classes with the same binary name,  and you want to know which one of them you are loading, you can only inspect the way that classloader tries to resolve a class name.